# HessianFieldException Error

Tags: java, hessian

I am using Hessian in my project through remote and client application.I am facing some problem in desalinization. My hessian application return Object which contain Set Of other object but at client side I am getting exception.

**nested exception is com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianFieldException:
java.util.Set cannot be assigned from null**

I also check with set null and also checked object don't have null set.

please tell me what I am missing and root cause of this problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?